# Confused about ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf, observablecollection

The MSDN page for ObservableCollection has the following sentence ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), under the *Remarks* section):

> WPF provides the ObservableCollection class, which is a built-in
>   implementation of a data collection that implements the
>   INotifyCollectionChanged interface.

Isn't this class part of .NET? So, why would WPF need to provide an implementation?  Guess I am missing something here, and would appreciate help to clarify.

Comment: I don't think this is meant to be taken literally, I think `ObservableCollection` originated in WPF around .NET 3.0 as part of the framework - but WPF had a big part in it since it was probably designed for data-binding scenarios. That's my 2 cents anyway, I'm sure someone can confirm

Comment: Why would this question deserve 3 downvotes and no explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested

`ObservableCollection<T>` is part of the framework, but it came out with the release of WPF in order to work with the binding engine (which needs `INotifyCollectionChanged` implementors to work)

Essentially it was designed with WPF in mind, so technically you could say WPF provided it.

The fact that you can use it for something else is just a bonus, but combined with the binding engine you get a lot of functionality for free